# Redirect p4 client to a output

Tags: perforce

I am trying to redirect the contents of 
 `p4 client` into a file `out`

Ex:- `p4 client > out`

But I get this error `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`
Can anyone pls help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p4 client -o clientname > out` This solved my problem

Comment: Indeed, without '-o', the 'p4 client' command wants to run your P4EDITOR.  In your case, this is Vim, and Vim didn't like the fact that stdout was redirected. Passing -o is the right thing to do.